# Py3k identical code executing differently in dynamic shell and from file

Tags: python-3.x

The code I'm using is:

```
import time
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

In the dynamic shell, this (as you would expect) outputs a formatted string, e.g. 03:21:35

When executing the exact same code from a file, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(time.strfime("%H:%M:%S"))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strfime'
```

Anybody got any idea as to why this might be happening, and more importantly, how to fix it?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.2 r32:88445 on WinXP and your code runs fine from the shell and from a file. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo:

```
print(time.strfime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

should be

```
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Well, that's awkward. Cheers.

Comment: It's okay...let's just pretend this didn't happen... ;-)